# Git SVN Clone Error

Tags: git, svn, clone

**On OS 10.6, git 2.0.0, svn 1.8.8.**

Trying to simply clone an svn repo using git results in:

```
$ git svn clone https://domain
```

**Error received is as below:**

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/ilia/Doejo/kolon/.git/
Repository has been moved: Repository moved temporarily to 
'https://vip-svn.wordpress.com/kolon'; please relocate at 
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.0.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 148
```

Have already tried reinstalling both `SVN` and `git` with brew, set my path to `/usr/local/bin/` instead of `/usr/bin/` - nothings been working.

At a loss as to what's going on, anybody else ever experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

It's misconfiguration at SVN-repository side or wrong URL of repo (not `https://vip-svn.wordpress.com/kolon`) on your side. Test URL from error-message with *native SVN-client*